# Bitwise conversion of decimal to integer

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I don't know if this is specific to JavaScript.

```
var pi = 3.14159265
alert(pi|0)
```

This will output 3.

Can someone explain what happens to the decimal fractions part during the bitwise OR operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bitwise or operator only operates on integer types, so the fractional component is silently stripped off the number. A bitwise or with zero will always result in the other operand. Therefore, you get 3.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operator only works on integers.

pi (3.14..) is converted to an INT which truncates the decimal places to 3.